# JSON parsing error, unsupported encoding or multiline in Data Factory

Tags: mongodb, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am using Azure's Data Factory tool to read a text file with a JSON structure from a Data Lake Storage Gen2 to transform the data and pass it to an Azure SQL DB.

I can test the connection with "Source settings" and it works successfully.

Sadly, I am receiving the following error msg when trying to import a "projection":

"JSON parsing error, unsupported encoding or multiline"

Under "Source options"->"JSON settings" I also tried it by activating the field "Single document". Without any success.

[{"_id":{"$oid":"xxxxxxx"},"uid":"xxxxxxxxxx","test-uid":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","url":"https://test","info":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)","test":"","dimension":"2560x1343",.....

The Data Preview, of course, shows the same error message.

I can't detect any JSON encoding errors. Any idea what I can do?
Any tutorial you can recommend for shifting JSON from Data Lake Gen2 into Azure SQL DB?

Update:

Due to the special character "$", the file were encoded in UTF-8-BOM. Reading the data from inside a Data Factory from the Data Lake Storage Gen2 this leads to the parsing errors.

Comment: I apologize the copy + paste error..I edited the beginning of the content.

Comment: Could you add a bit more of your JSON?  It is hard to really help you when we can't see the bulk of what is likely to be causing the error

Comment: I just increased a bit the content. The data comes from a MongoDB. Some other field names also contain "[" or "]" characters.

Comment: Based on the error message, have you looked at what the encoding of the file is and whether your JSON meets the format specs defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#json-file-patterns)?

Comment: I downloaded an example file from my blobcontainer in Azure (the Data Lake Gen2) and it shows it is encoded with UTF-8-BOM. That could be really a problem and could be the case because of the special character "$". I will check that.

Comment: Hi@Matzka I am also researching this issue, do you mean that the parsing errors caused by the special character "$"?

Comment: Hi Jospeh. Yes. Because of the character $ Azure stored the files in my Data Lake with an encoding of UTF-8-BOM. The problem is, when I try to read from that Data Lake, Azure can't deal with UTF-8-BOM. I just remove the $ and everything works then.

Comment: @Matzka Very glad to hear that you solved it!  We could help you post it as answer. I don't know why you never mark other's useful answer.  If you could accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). Others can know you error is solved  This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. You also could post it by yourself instead of post it in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations that you solved it:

"I just remove the $ and everything works then".

Please see the question update.

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.